# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host on vnx machine (linux)

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I changed the password of my linux machine . I was able to login for sometime and after that I am not able to ssh.
I am getting the following error:

```
ssh es4042cs -v
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to es4042cs [10.66.213.242] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
**ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host**
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to login as root, is that your intention ?

Answer (score 1):

I add this exact same issue yesterday, In fact you probably declare a hostname in your ssh config and using a different one to connect.
In my case I had declare the hostname `foobar` and I was trying to connect on `192.168.0.55`. I was ending up with the exact same behavior.